# Como fazer pesquisa e mostrar os dados

Tags: php, sql

Bem .. Eu preciso fazer uma pesquisa em uma tabela e através dessa pesquisa puxar os dados de outra. Mas acabei me perdendo na lógica ...

Exemplo do que estou fazendo:

O usuário informa o dado que ele quer:

```
    <td >
        <font >Nota:</font>
    </td>
    <td >
        <input name="tx_nota_fisc" type="text" maxlength="15" size="10" value="">
        <button type="button" style="width:30" onClick="f_veri_nota();"><image src="../sai_imag/ref1.ico" > </button>                   
    </td>
```

`f_veri_nota()` chama a próxima tela passando o dado que foi digitado.

```
w_tx_nota = document.sai_frm_alte_novo_cara_peri.tx_nota_fisc.value;
document.getElementById("ifrm_peri").src = ("sai_frm_alte_novo_cara_peri1.php?w_tx_nota="+w_tx_nota);
```

E na entrada da tela eu verifico se o dado digitado se encontra na `tabela Nota`. E se caso tiver eu faço um `select` pegando a `sequencia` dessa nota digitada e comparo com a `fk_nota` que tenho em outra tabela, para assim pegar os dados.

```
<?
$w_tx_nota = $_GET['w_tx_nota'];
$w_querybusca = "select * from sai_nota where num_nf = '$w_tx_nota';"; --> verifica se existe o dado digitado na tabela

$w_querybusca = "select " --> E nesse select quero pegar a sequencia do num_nf e comparar ele com uma fk que se encontra em outra tabela. Para assim popular os campos.
?>
```

O problema: Como pegar a sequencia de um campo texto e comparar com a fk que esta em outra tabela?

Estrutura:

```
create table sai_nota
(
  sequencia_nota integer not null,
  num_nf character varying(9)
)

create table peri
(
  sequencia_peri integer not null,
  fk_nota serial not null,
  //outros campos
)
```

***Nomes fictícios**

Comment: Eu não consegui assimilar muito bem sua questão. Você poderia reformulá-la ou explicar melhor?

Comment: É como se tivesse o nome e o cpf numa tabela e o resto das informações do indivíduo em outra tabela?

Comment: Você pode incluir na pergunta as estruturas das tabelas envolvidas, pra gente entender melhor?

Comment: Isso mesmo @MarcosVinicius, e o cpf está como fk nessa outra tabela!

Comment: Pode ou quer fazer tudo isso numa só consulta e mandar o resultado para a outra página @Bruno?

Comment: Pode ser em uma só consulta, pois acho que seria uma maneira mais simples de se trabalhar @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira!

Comment: A galera já está respondendo mas melhora o nome desses atributos/variáveis, tanto no banco como no código garanto que não vai se arrepender. De uma lida sobre "Nomenclaturas de variavéis..."

Comment: Eu mencionei na pergunta, esses são nomes "fictícios" !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi direito, você pode fazer tudo numa única query, não precisa separar:

```
SELECT
    peri.* /* substitua pela lista de campos que quer */
FROM sai_nota
    INNER JOIN peri
    ON peri.fk_nota = sai_nota.sequencia_nota
WHERE num_nf = '$w_tx_nota';
```

Eu também usaria uma [query parametrizada, com mysqli ou PDO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php), em vez de embutir a variável do PHP direto na string da query. Isso te deixaria menos vulnerável a SQL injection.

Comment: @ bfavaretto, era isso mesmo que eu precisava! Obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar!